# Sorting Multi level dataframe index level0, based on value of index level1 at specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, multi-level

I have this multi level dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
sites = pd.Index(['CCC', 'RRR','TTT', 'SSS'], name='SITELIST')
vvv = pd.DataFrame({'KK':[1,2,3,4],'GG':[4,3,4,5], 'RR':[1,5,1,8]}, index = sites)
ttt = pd.DataFrame({'KK':[11,22,33,34],'GG':[23,33,34,35], 'RR':[1,2,2,1]}, index = sites)
df = pd.concat([vvv, ttt], axis=0, keys=["VVV", "TTT"], names=['Sensor', 'Site'])
df = df.swaplevel().sort_index(level=0).reindex(['VVV','TTT'],level=1)
print(df)
```

dataframe :

```
             KK  GG  RR
Site Sensor            
CCC  VVV      1   4   1
     TTT     11  23   1
RRR  VVV      2   3   5
     TTT     22  33   2
SSS  VVV      4   5   8
     TTT     34  35   1
TTT  VVV      3   4   1
     TTT     33  34   2
```

How do i sort the dataframe index level0 'Site' using each value on index level1 'VVV' at column RR
The expected result as such:

```
             KK  GG  RR
Site Sensor            
CCC  VVV      1   4   1 <-
     TTT     11  23   1
TTT  VVV      3   4   1 <-
     TTT     33  34   2
RRR  VVV      2   3   5 <-
     TTT     22  33   2
SSS  VVV      4   5   8 <-
     TTT     34  35   1
```

I have tried to sort with

```
print(df.sort_values('RR'))
```

But get unexpected

```
             KK  GG  RR
Site Sensor            
CCC  VVV      1   4   1
     TTT     11  23   1
SSS  TTT     34  35   1
TTT  VVV      3   4   1
RRR  TTT     22  33   2
TTT  TTT     33  34   2
RRR  VVV      2   3   5
SSS  VVV      4   5   8
```

Thank you.

Comment: I need the index level0 which is 'Site' is sorted by the value of col RR but on;y the one in index level1 VVV (or each row VVV). If I just sort_value the col RR; then value on row TTT will also be sorted, thus create something such as:
`print(df.sort_values('RR'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can first `reset_index` to sort and get the correct order of `site`:

```
df = (df.reset_index().sort_values(["Sensor", "RR", "Site"], ascending=(False, True, True)))

   Site Sensor  KK  GG  RR
0  CCC    VVV   1   4   1
6  TTT    VVV   3   4   1
2  RRR    VVV   2   3   5
4  SSS    VVV   4   5   8
1  CCC    TTT  11  23   1
5  SSS    TTT  34  35   1
3  RRR    TTT  22  33   2
7  TTT    TTT  33  34   2
```

From here using the result to construct an ordered `pd.Categorical` so you can obtain the final result:

```
df["Site"] = pd.Categorical(df["Site"], categories=df["Site"].unique(), ordered=True)

print (df.sort_values("Site").set_index(["Site","Sensor"]))

             KK  GG  RR
Site Sensor            
CCC  VVV      1   4   1
     TTT     11  23   1
TTT  VVV      3   4   1
     TTT     33  34   2
RRR  VVV      2   3   5
     TTT     22  33   2
SSS  VVV      4   5   8
     TTT     34  35   1
```

Comment: I was thinking it should just be as
`df.sort_index('Site', by=[index['Sensor'], col['RR']])`
should be more intuitive :)